# Is Umbraco compatible with MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco, asp.net-mvc-5

I've got an Umbraco 6.1.5 project that I'd be interested in upgrading to ASP.Net MVC 5, but I'm not sure if there are any MVC 4 dependencies in Umbraco that would cause breaking changes. Thought it would be a good idea to see if anyone else knew or had tried it before I go spend a day or two trying to upgrade without knowing whether or not it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not supported according to
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-3560

Answer (score 7):

Umbraco got MVC 5 support in version 7.2.2

Source: http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2015/2/19/umbraco-722-and-625-released